# Settings Save slow down app

Tags: c#

I've a list of element with a checkbox. The items are available inside a `Checkbox`, and I save all the checked value inside my settings app, in particular, I've a field called `available_countries` and I save all the event inside this field.

Essentially when a item is checked a fire the event associated:

```
private void AvailableCountries_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = sender as CheckBox;

    if (item.Content.ToString() == "All")//first item of the list need to check all
    {
        Vm.AvailableNations.Select(c => { c.IsChecked = true; return c; }).ToList(); //Execute the IsChecked update through linq
    }

    //Check if the checked value is already added in the settings..
    var nationsArr = Properties.Settings.Default.available_countries.Split(';');

    foreach (var country in nationsArr)
    {
        if (country == item.Content.ToString()) //Nation already added!
        {
           return;
        }
    }

    Properties.Settings.Default.available_countries += item.Content.ToString() + ";"; //Separator
   Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Now this code working well and is very simple, but I noticed that `.Save()` at the end slow down the app performance, infact when I click on the first item of the `ComboBox` that have as `.Content` : `All` I need to change all the `IsChecked` property of all element.

I need also to check if the value is already added in the Settings.

I noticed that if I remove the last line of code I doesn't see the delay time, about 1/2 seconds.

There is a way to improve it?

Comment: to make your linq query shorter: `Vm.AvailableNations.Select(c => { return c.IsChecked == true; }).ToList();`

Comment: Pretty hard to explain away, tends to be environmental.   Try another machine.  In general this is something you should *never* do.  It is too risky, if there's any reason for the new setting to cause your program to crash then it will crash forever.  Excessively hard to repair.  Only save settings when your program exits normally.

Comment: @HansPassant well I've an i7 of last gen and 16gb or ram. I think that I need to improve my code instead of change the pc

Comment: It doesn't take much to cripple a nice machine like that, just crappy anti-malware.  It is besides the point anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the settings are stored in an XML file in the user's profile, so yes, whenever you save your settings, a short delay will be there. No way to change that.

A possible solution in your case would be to not save the settings when the check box is checked, but in some other event (like for example an OK button of the settings dialog, etc).

Another solution would be to start a background task that changes the values and saves the settings, but you'd have to make sure this is properly synchronized.

A third solution would be to just change the settings object, but not save until the application is closed. That would slow down the process of closing the application, but ...

Comment: I though to create a json file to store all this stuff

Comment: Why? Then you have the additional overhead of serializing to JSON... No, I'd just use the builtin settings mechanism and try to save asynchronously. The thing is, you *have* to save *at some point*. No matter whether you use the builtin mechanism or any other implementation. That's a given, so using JSON won't help. Maybe you should determine whether saving *right now* is necessary? You could also save then the application quits.

Comment: Uhm you guess right, I'll revisionate my code to make it in sync

Comment: Now that I think about it, saving when the window/application is closed is probably the neatest solution, as it doesn't require any async processing.

Comment: As Thorsten Dittmar already said: start a new background task (`Systen.Threading.Task.TaskFactory.StartNew(t => Properties.Settings.Default.Save();).Start();`)

Comment: @Radinator What if the user clicks various check boxes quickly? Don't you think that this should somehow be synchronized if not serialized?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Could you please post an example of your synchronization logic? Thanks.

Comment: I don't have one at hand right now, I'd have to think about it, too. Still, my approach would be to save the settings when the windows is closed instead of every time something is selected.